# What will happen if I dd an image of a disk into a partition

Tags: filesystems, partition, disk

I am wondering what would happend if I tried to dd a disk image into a partition. I explain myself:

I have an SSD Hard Drive that contains two partitions:

```
/dev/sda
            sda1
            sda2
```

And I have a disk image, made from a vdi file (virtual box virtual disk) that contains:

```
/dev/sdb
            sdb1
            sdb2
```

Now, what would happend if I launch:

```
sudo dd if=raw.img of=/dev/sda2
```

Would I get:

```
/dev/sda
            sda1
            sda2
                    sda21
                    sda22
```

Or would I get:

```
/dev/sda
            sda1
            sda21
            sda22
```

Or would it just not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would not work in that you would get sda2 with garbage inside, but a small change can make it work;

You need to find the offset of each partition in the img and dd each one into its own (larger) partition on the destination.

Comment: This was what I was afraid of. Thank you!